# Laravel Fortify returns Not Found

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-fortify

I send a xhr request to `/login` route. It does login, but the response is an html with text `Not Found`. I realize that fortify is saying this coz it cant find the logged in view. I have enabled views, `'views' => true` in `config/Fortify.php`. But I want Fortify to return a success response text after successful login. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise your response based on the request type:

```
public function func(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json('AJAX response', 200);
    }

    return view('my-view');
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted! TY!